# How to call another method from a different class in the same java project

Tags: java, methods

How do I call a method from a different class in a java project? I have two different classes, each are in the same java project. The name of the first class is Applications, while the name of the second class in ShowChar. These classes are each in the same java project. What I must do is obtain a string input from the user, then I must obtain an integer from the user, then I must tell the user what letter lies on the integer they chose. I did all of that. That is what the class ShowChar does, but what I am supposed to do is call a method from the ShowChar class in the Applications class. I can not get this to work. Please help.

Here is my ShowChar class-

```
public class ShowChar {


char showChar(String text, int index)
{
    char letter='0';

    if((text.equals(null)))
    {
    System.out.print("Invalid input string. The process"
                          + "terminates");
    }
    else{ 
        if(index<0 || index>=text.length())
        {
            System.out.print("Invalid input for index\n"
                           + "The first character of the text is " + text.charAt(0));
            return letter;
        }
    else{
        if(index>=0 && index<text.length()) 
        {
        System.out.println("The character you asked for is: " + text.charAt(index));
        return letter;
        }
    }
    }

return letter;
}
}`
```

Here is what I have gotten figure out with my Applications class-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);




    String text=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the text: ");
    System.out.println("Enter the index: ");
    int index= keyboard.nextInt();

    ShowChar sc = new ShowChar();




    System.out.println("character found: " + sc.showChar(text, index) );



}
```

}

Down at the bottom I am supposed to print to the console the letter that I found, but i cant seem to get it  to work. Whenever I run my program with any input the System.out.println statement always comes back with "character found: 0" I must be missing something.

Comment: You are calling it correctly (if you weren't, it wouldn't compile).  I suggest you use a debugger or put System.out.println statements in to see what the text value is you are passing in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't assign a value to letter

```
char showChar(String text, int index)
{
    char letter='0';

    if((text.equals(null)))
    {
    System.out.print("Invalid input string. The process"
                          + "terminates");
    }
    else{ 
        if(index<0 || index>=text.length())
        {
            System.out.print("Invalid input for index\n"
                           + "The first character of the text is " + text.charAt(0));
            return letter;
        }
    else{
        if(index>=0 && index<text.length()) 
        {
        System.out.println("The character you asked for is: " + text.charAt(index));
        letter = text.charAt(index);
        return letter;
        }
    }
    }

return letter;
}
```

Comment: quick question, whats the difference between text.equals(null) and text==null?

Comment: .equals compares values while '==' compare the references

Answer (score 0):

you make initialization as :

```
char letter='0';
```

but you never assign the char a value later, that is why it return "0" which is the default value .

suggestion :

```
if(index>=0 && index<text.length()) 
        {
        System.out.println("The character you asked for is: " + text.charAt(index));
        letter = text.charAt(index));
        return letter;
        }
```